# Where does VSCode save the context about open files?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am aware that I am asking for an implementation detail but I want to hack something for my use case and hence the question.

My use case: I use an on-demand instance where source code is hosted at work. This means I get a new machine (let's say every day) where I open the same source folder (but hosted on that remote machine). Because of this, the context of opened files in editor gets lost between sessions.

I am curious where does VSCode save the information about open files in a workspace. If I know that, I am hoping I can copy that file at the end of day before I give up an on-demand instance AND when I get the next instance (which may have a different remote url but same file paths), I can somehow hack this file to open all the editors from previous session in the new on-demand. Does my question make sense? Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: very similar question: [Where VS Code stores the list of open files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48014141/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows the workspace state is stored here:

```
%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage
```

And on Linux:

```
~/.config/Code/User/workspaceStorage
```

Every workspace has a subfolder here with a hashed name. To find out which one belongs to your workspace, open the contained `workspace.json`, which looks like this:

```json
{
  "folder": "file:///c%3A/some/path"
}
```

Choose the one that matches your workspace folder and copy the complete folder.

However, I am not sure how VS Code calculates the hashes for the folder names, so maybe it won't use the same hash again in your new instance. But this definitely is the place where the information is stored, so it's worth a try.