# Where does VSCode store its Most Recently Used (MRU) list of .NET projects and solutions on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, storage, mru

Where does VSCode store its Most Recently Used (MRU) list of .NET projects and solutions on Windows?

And also is there some open source code to fetch VSCode's MRUs?

I scanned all files in this dir (recursive) `C:\Users\pat\AppData\Roaming\Code` with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you it should be in `C:\Users\pat\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb`; this file is an SQLite database and you can look around for tools that open this kind of file (because it won't be readable as plain text) to see what's inside and decide whether you can sync it across machines (if that's what you're after).

Also reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014141/where-vs-code-stores-the-list-of-open-files), there's very useful stuff over there.